# Which losing team has had the most possession time?

Tags: american-football, nfl

In the NFL, which team has had the greatest time in possession but still lost the match?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one post - you are more than welcome to ask multiple questions in separate posts though!

Comment: With regards to this specific question, are you prepared to include overtime and playoff games? I don't know if the possession time is available, but [the longest game in NFL history](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/197112250kan.htm#all_team_stats) will set a baseline for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The '96 Rams, or the '09 Dolphins

According to [Statmuse.com](https://www.statmuse.com/nfl/ask/which-team-has-the-most-time-of-possession-in-a-game), the 1996 St. Louis Rams lost [this game](https://www.statmuse.com/nfl/game/10-27-1996-stl-@-bal-10319) to the Baltimore Ravens, despite having the ball for 45:43. If you're limiting the question to non-overtime games, then the record belongs to the 2009 Miami Dolphins, who lost [this game](https://www.statmuse.com/nfl/game/9-21-2009-ind-@-mia-13632) (at home, no less!) to the Indianapolis Colts despite having the ball for 45:07.

(The Statmuse database goes back to the 1991 season so there is a possibility games before that may have greater time in possession)